# Where is Visual Studio source file directory change option

Tags: c++, visual-studio, solution, visual-studio-2019

I've been trying for hours to change the source path. I couldn't find anything on project properties, and I couldn't find anything on the internet either.

I want to put all my source files in a directory named "src" 
like `$mysolution-path)/src` and I also want to put library files in the `/lib` directory, but I can't do it.

Where is this option? Is there an option like this. I want to keep my work clean and tidy, but it seems like it's impossible in Visual Studio unlike in IntelliJ IDE.

Comment: IIRC it's not in the project settings, but you have to change the properties of the "folders" in the project tree.

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing it:

1. remove your files from the VS project
2. move the files in explorer
3. add the files to the VS project

Answer (score 3):

In Project properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General there is the voice: "Additional Include Directories". You can specify there all the folders you are using for your project, thus you just need to create the folders you need manually and then add the paths there.

About lib files, under Project properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General there is the voice: Additional Library Directories. Just add there the paths to the lib folders.